# Android RelativeLayout not moving items

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create a viewGroup that takes the form of a 'post' and I need this view to have an image in the upper left and then a username and content to the right of that post, aligned with eachother however I can not seem to get the layouts to move. They just stay overlapping.

```
public ViewGroup generateViewGroup(Context context){
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Point p = new Point();
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(p);
    TextView tvUsername = new TextView(context);
    tvUsername.setText(userName);
    TextView tvPostContent = new TextView(context);
    tvPostContent.setText(postContent);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpTvUsername = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lpTvUsername.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,0);
    lpTvUsername.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,0);
    tvUsername.setLayoutParams(lpTvUsername);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpTvPostContent = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lpTvPostContent.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,0);
    lpTvPostContent.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,1);
    tvPostContent.setLayoutParams(lpTvPostContent);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    if (userPic==null) Log.e("generateViewGroup","userPic is null");
    iv.setImageDrawable(userPic);
    rl.addView(iv, 0);
    rl.addView(tvUsername,1);
    rl.addView(tvPostContent);
    rl.setLayoutParams(lp);

}
```

Comment: Any specific reason that you do not want to inflate an XML?

Comment: I am trying to stick to the java because we have many other classes working together with this one (http requests and such) so it would not be easy to do in xml

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code in the following way and set it as the content view of a blank Activity:

```
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Point p = new Point();
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(p);
    //
    // integer ID's for all the Views;
    int ivID = 0x0FD;
    int tvUserNameID = 0x0FE;
    int tvPostContentID = 0x0FF;
    //
    TextView tvUsername = new TextView(context);
    //
    tvUsername.setId(tvUserNameID); // Set the ID
    //
    tvUsername.setText(userName);
    TextView tvPostContent = new TextView(context);
    //
    tvPostContent.setId(tvPostContentID); // Set the ID
    //
    tvPostContent.setText(postContent);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
    //
    iv.setId(ivID); // Set the ID
    //
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpTvUsername = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //
    //lpTvUsername.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,0);
    //lpTvUsername.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,0);
    //
    // Reference the ID not the Index;
    lpTvUsername.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,ivID);
    lpTvUsername.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,ivID);
    //
    tvUsername.setLayoutParams(lpTvUsername);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpTvPostContent = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //
    // lpTvPostContent.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,0);
    // lpTvPostContent.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,1);
    //
    // Reference the ID not the Index;
    lpTvPostContent.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,ivID);
    lpTvPostContent.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,tvUserNameID);
    //
    tvPostContent.setLayoutParams(lpTvPostContent);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    if (userPic==null) Log.e("generateViewGroup","userPic is null");
    iv.setImageDrawable(userPic);
    rl.addView(iv, 0);
    rl.addView(tvUsername,1);
    rl.addView(tvPostContent);
    rl.setLayoutParams(lp);
    setContentView(rl);
```

Mainly the problem was taking place because while setting the LayoutParams you were referencing the **index** not the **Views ID**.